# Taking an external disk offline safely *without* locking its volumes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, storage, flush

I am working on a feature in which the DB resides on an external storage device such as a Fibre channel drive. As part of the shutdown process, I want to take the storage drive offline. Currently I do it this way (code is in C++ but this is only a high level description):

For each volume in the disk:

1. Flush it (by calling FlushFileBuffers with its handle)
2. Lock it (via calling DeviceIoControl with the FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME code)
3. Dismount it (via the FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME code)
4. Take it offline (via the IOCTL_VOLUME_OFFLINE code)

Only if all the volumes associated with the disk go through the series of the above 4 steps successfully, I take the disk offline, by using the IOTCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES and IOCTL_UPDATE_DISK_PROPERTIES control codes.

The problem I ran into is that very frequently, users open files that reside on the external disk via other programs such as notepad. In that case, step 2 - Locking the volume - will fail and in turn this will fail the entire shutdown attempt, which causes the program to get stuck because I don't allow the shutdown to complete without the lock being successful. The reason is that from what I understand, this is the only reliable way to force a full flush of all unwritten data to the disk, which is essential in preventing the disk from being in an inconsistent state (files ending up as half-written, etc.).

So basically I'd like to know if there's a reliable way to guarantee a full flush of data to the disk without locking its volumes. I noticed that for example the MS Failover Cluster doesn't lock any volume when taking a shared disk offline, does anyone happen to know how that works?

Thanks!

Amit

Comment: I think you can just skip the FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME step?  The documentation says that the only difference between a lock and a dismount is that the lock explicitly checks for open files whereas the dismount doesn't.  (Well, the lock also prevents other processes from remounting the volume, but I don't *think* that will be a problem.)

Comment: (I assume you mean `IOCTL_VOLUME_OFFLINE` when you say `FSCTL_OFFLINE_VOLUME` ?  The latter doesn't seem to exist.)

Comment: @Harry  Yes - IOCTL_VOLUME_OFFLINE is what I use. I've corrected the question as well.

I'm referring to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364575(v=vs.85).aspx) when I mention the flushing aspect, they write:
"The system flushes all cached data to the volume before locking it. For example, any data held in a lazy-write cache is written to the volume.". The same does not seem to be true for FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME.

Comment: The documentation for FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME doesn't explicitly say that cached data is flushed, but I *think* that's only because flushing the cache is implicit in the fact that the volume is being dismounted.  Someone else might know for sure.  Have you tried locking the volume after it is dismounted?

Comment: That's very interesting! I think you can't really lock the volume after dismounting it, but after some googl'ing I did find some indications, like [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/2wmjT5SCyfM) that dismounting also forces the system to flush cached data into the disk. I'll try to verify that it really does that. Thanks!